# Set a List of property to default value

Tags: c#, list, properties

I have a class

```
public class Request
 {
    public List<SiteEnum> Sites { get; set; } = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SiteEnum)).Cast<SiteEnum>   ().ToList();
    public ReportTypeEnum ReportType { get; set; } = ReportTypeEnum.Daily;
    public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I have set default values to these properties.
I have an HTTP Post Function trigger, when the request comes in with the Request Body.

```
requestBody : {
  "sites": [ "xyz"
  ],
  "reportType": 1,
  "reportDate": "2023-03-23T11:45:31.187Z",
}`
```

I then deserialize it like:

```
ReportRequest reportRequest;
reportRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportRequest>(requestBody);
```

But the List Sites property does not take the values I send in the request and  always take all the values present in SiteEnum class.

How can I make this work that if I don't pass any value to the list property, it take all the values but when I provide the values in the request body then it take only those values.

Comment: Have you tried to make a custom get set with private field? (private "Type" "Name"; get { return "Name" } set { if (value == null) "Name" = "stuff" else "Name" = value }) or something like that?

Comment: Have you got a string to enum converter anywhere in your middleware?
Enum's are structs that derive from an int in C# so it would only map to your enum value if you passed in the integer variation. For a string, you'd need to have a string to enum converter somewhere. Normally in the middleware when you set up your serialisation options